# Working with a flattened array

Tags: php, arrays, json, flatten

Because of an external service, I am *forced* to store all my data using a flattened JSON Object.

Normally, I would retrieve my JSON Object, turn it into a PHP array, and use it like so:

**Decode this JSON Object into an array named `$array`**

```
{
  "info":{
    "title:":"This is a test title",
    "owner":"1"
  },
  "data":{
    "page_1":{
      "first_name":null,
      "address":{
        "address_line1":null,
        "address_line2":null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then do something like this:

```
$page_1 = $array['data']['page_1'];
echo $page_1['first_name'];
echo $page_1['address']['address_line1'];
```

Instead I have to do something like this:

```
{
  "info.title:": "This is a test title",
  "info.owner": "1",
  "data.page_1.first_name": null,
  "data.page_1.address.address_line1": null,
  "data.page_1.address.address_line2": null
}
```

So I guess my question is, what is the best way to work with a flattened array in PHP?

- Should I un-flatten it on the spot?
- Should I just use it like `echo $array['data.page_1.first_name'];`?
- Something that I'm not thinking of

What do you think the best practice would be?

Comment: why whats the problem? your just not comfortable using nested arrays?

Comment: Asking for "best practice" is a symptom that question is off-topic. What is your problem?

Comment: I think that this external service is stupid. Besides you should be able to use JSON with multiple levels.

Comment: I just don't know how to work within a flattened array. For example,  finding all the `first_name`'s in my JSON (if I were to have multiple of them). In a nested array, I could search for `first_name`, now they are more "unique". I'm sorry if I'm not making sense, flattened arrays just seem a lot more confusing. @sectus

Comment: Wrap it or transform to comfortable structure.

Comment: Is it worth the resources to un-flatten? If it's a HUGE array. @sectus

Comment: Just make some performance tests.